# "No-go" theorems and goldstone bosons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higher-spin

There are "no-go" theorems who forbid interaction through soft helicity 3 and higher massless particles and soft interaction between massless fermions with spin more than $\frac{3}{2}$. But if fermions aqquire masses, than such theorem doesn't hold. In many realistic theories fermions aqquire masses through Higgs-like mechanism. So does some "no-go" theorem exist for case of presense of goldstone bosons in theory?

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Consider adding references to make the question more accessible to the reader and focus the answers.